# Assigning a value of one column to another column if certain constrains apply

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to assign numbers to certain cells of a column. My current approach is not working. Could somebody help me to find an alternative approach that assigns the values of `df['A1']` to `df['A2']` for the rows where `df['B2']` is `notnull` while `df['A2']` is equal to `isnull`.

This is my current approach :

```
df['A2'].loc[(df['B2'].notnull()) & (df['A2'].isnull()) ]=df['A1'].loc[(df['B2].notnull()) &(df['A2'].isnull()) ].tolist()
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mask = df['B2'].notna() & df['A2'].isna()
df.loc[mask,'A2'] = df.loc[mask,'A1'].to_numpy()
```